# second order Taylor expansion to approximate ℓp norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading "Non-Sparse Multiple Kernel Fisher Discriminant Analysis" paper. At page 6 (612), $\lVert \beta\rVert$ is approximated by second order Taylor expansion. The resulting approximations are:

$\lVert \beta\rVert_p^p \approx \frac{p(p-1)}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n \beta\ _j^{p-2}\beta\ _j^{2} - \sum_{j=1}^n p(p-2)\beta\ _j^{p-1}\beta\ _j + \frac{p(p-3)}{2} + 1$

I need help to understand this. Any reference regarding this theory will also be helpful.

Comment: What is $\tilde{\beta}$? (I'm not going to chase your reference.)

Comment: At some point in the editing the tildes went away, and now the formula makes no sense (since now the first sum without the constant factor is exactly the desired quantity).

Comment: $\beta tilde $ is the current estimate of $\beta$ in an iterative process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varphi(x) := x^p$, $x > 0$, and let $\widetilde{x}> 0$ be fixed.
Using the second order Taylor expansion you get
$$
\varphi(x) = \varphi(\widetilde{x}) + \varphi'(\widetilde{x})(x-\widetilde{x}) + \frac{1}{2}\varphi''(\widetilde{x}) (x-\widetilde{x})^2 + o(|x-\widetilde{x}|^2).
$$
Since $\varphi'(x) = p x^{p-1}$ and $\varphi''(x) = p(p-1) x^{p-2}$, with some algebra you get
$$
x^p \simeq \frac{1}{2}p(p-1) \widetilde{x}^{p-2} x^2 - p(p-2) \widetilde{x}^{p-1}x + \left(\frac{p(p-3)}{2} + 1\right)\widetilde{x}^p.
$$
Now, writing this equivalence for every $j$ using $x=\beta_j$ and $\widetilde{x} = \widetilde{\beta}_j$, summing up and **assuming** $\|\widetilde{\beta}\|_p = 1$ you get your expansion.